# Xcode is crashing in SpriteKit

Tags: xcode

Make a project->Game->SpriteKit (no matter Swift or С), click on gamescene.sks in project navigator and then xcode is crashing.
OS X 10.11 
Xcode 7.3

Anyone have the same?
Thanks

Comment: Any error messages/logs??

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Mac OS propose to send a report to apple with big log. I look on it quickly and find interesting lines:

Comment: "...Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7D175
Assertion failed: (*shader), function xglCompileShader, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet/Jet-2.6.1/Jet/xgl_utils.mm, line 24...."

Comment: and more "Error Code:      0x020000b8"

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm using vmware and I have the same error when i'm clicking on "GameScene.sks"