# SpriteKit .sks Files Crash Xcode 10 When Assigning Texture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode10

### Am I missing something obvious?

For reasons unknown, Xcode 10 keeps crashing on me when I go to assign a texture to a **named** sprite using the Scene Editor. After having to delete and recreate my .sks files a couple times, I decided to try and reproduce the issue using Xcode's game template. The steps I took to do this are as follows:

- Open Xcode and select **Create a new Xcode project**.
- Choose the **Game** template, name the project **Test** and save it somewhere, i.e. your desktop.
- Drag any image asset into **Assets.xcassets**. I used this green square:

  [image: green square]
- Open **GameScene.sks** and drag a **Color Sprite** onto the scene.

[image]

- Name the sprite something descriptive like **square_green**.
- Attempt to set the texture in this field:

[image]

Other similar questions on Stack Overflow:

[Xcode is crashing in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390504/xcode-is-crashing-in-spritekit)

[XCode 9 Crashing while setting a Texture in SKScene in Spritekit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879397/xcode-9-crashing-while-setting-a-texture-in-skscene-in-spritekit)

If I do not set a name for the color sprite prior to assigning a texture, everything works fine. However, if Xcode is forced to crash at least one time, I have to delete the .sks file completely just to get Xcode to open again.

For the time being I've decided to avoid the trouble all together and just assign the textures programmatically in the didMove(to:) of my SKScene class:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let greenSquare = childNode(withName: "square_green") as! SKSpriteNode
    greenSquare.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "square_green")
}
```

Comment: Could you try stripping metadata as suggested in MikeJfromVA answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50779974/1033581?

Comment: Did you report the crash to Apple? https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Each time the crash happens I send it to Apple but I have not submitted a formal radar yet.

Comment: Been struggling with this one since 2016. Tried every workaround suggested. Now that my projects a lot bigger it just so much worse. Seems to be a problem with Assets.xcassets. My new workaround (until a formal fix by Apple) is avoiding the Assets.xcassets and simply putting new images in a separate folder and then I can magically assign them without the nasty crash.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and later I moved the images out of Assets.xcassets and the problem was solved. I guess the image can't be placed in Assets.xcassets.

Comment: -> New Group, named Images, then move the image from Assets.xcassets to Images